# Use andWhere under IF condition in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-model

Just a quick question.
I need to create a find query in Yii2 where an andWhere is only present if a variable is true.

```
public function getCheckBoxItems($holiday=false)
{
    $Items = Items::find()->where(['type'=>'checkbox']);
    Yii::info(print_r($Items,1), 'c');

    if($holiday)
        $Items->andWhere(['<>','category','holiday']);

    $Items->All();
    foreach($Items as $Item)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This doesn't work

However this deos work and i expected it to.

```
$Items = Items::find()->where(['type'=>'checkbox'])->andWhere(['<>','category','holiday'])->All();
```

How do I only add the andWhere based on the `$holiday` variable

Thanks in advance

Regards

Liam

**UPDATE**
i have found one way, but i am sure there is a better way

```
    if($holiday)
        $Items = Items::find()->where(['type'=>'checkbox'])->andWhere(['<>','category','holiday'])->All();
    else            
        $Items = Items::find()->where(['type'=>'checkbox'])->All();
```

Comment: use only `andWhere()` in both.

Comment: But i only what the andWhere if $holiday is true

Comment: it work both ways, $holiday is true or false.

Comment: This should be `$Items = $Items->All();`...

Answer (score 7):

Just to make your code more clear and readable, you should simply try :

```
$itemsQuery = Items::find()->where(['type'=>'checkbox']);

if($holiday)
    $itemsQuery->andWhere(['<>','category','holiday']);

$items = $itemsQuery->all();
foreach($items as $item)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to store `$items` result at each checkpoint:

```
public function getCheckBoxItems($holiday=false)
{
$Items = Items::find()->where(['type'=>'checkbox']);
Yii::info(print_r($Items,1), 'c');

if($holiday)
    $Items->andWhere(['<>','category','holiday']);

$Items = $Items->All();
foreach($Items as $Item)
{
    //do something
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need `$Items = $Items->andWhere(['<>','category','holiday']);`